# get updated data attribute after button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, jquery-plugins

I wrote a plugin which takes the data attribute from a node and do some work,

issue : when first time page loads, it works fine. but when after page load i change the data attribute "data-range" to some other value and then when i click the button it is showing the old value not the updated one.
here How I am accessing the attribute in my plugin.

```
var svgThis = this.$element.parent().parent().parent().find('svg').attr('id');
var dataRangeString = $("#"+svgThis).find(".focus").data("range");
```

but even ".focus" data-range got changed and I try to print the new datarangeString its showing me the old value which was displayed when pages loads first time.
I am stuck and its very important for me.
Any idea how to fix this issue.

details :-

1. I have a plugin to create chart,in that I am changing the data attribute when chart is zoomed.
   eg. when first chart is loaded the data-range is 1jan1015 to 8aug2015
   after the zoom data-range updated 4april2015 to 8june2015
2. I have a plugin to export the data of the chart.so first time when page loads i got the data 1jan1015 to 8aug2015 (fine)
   but after i zoom the data and again click the button its showing me same data.

svg-plugin sample code

```
drawSvg(){
  ....// code to generate svg element with data provided
  generateMenu(this.$element.selector,this.options.data);
  .... // code to update the data when zoomed
  focus.attr("data-range",x.domain()); //focus is object created in d3 of a node <g class="focus">
}
```

generateMenuplugin

```
generateMenu(){
  var svgThis = this.$element.parent().parent().parent().find('svg').attr('id');
var dataRangeString = $("#"+svgThis).find(".focus").data("range");
}
```

Comment: Can you post a sample code ?

Comment: how you are updating the data-range and where you are trying to get? This is not clear as per current code. Can you post more.

Comment: i guess now you guys can have idea about the problem, I updated the post

Comment: We see how you access element data, but the question is: How do you update/change the element data? That code is missing.

Comment: @SaurabhSinha Not related to actual problem but don't use `parent().parent().parent()` use `.closest("svg")`

Comment: The way you set element's data in `jQuery` is not by changing its attribute, you should use `focus.data('range', x.domain())`. You should really debug it and write to console what you store in data. Also if the `focus` is global element, you should use it in both functions (it could be you are setting the data to one object, but reading from another).

Comment: I am not setting by jquery, I am adding attribute by d3 which is data-range

Comment: I can see in debugger that data attribute is getting changed on zoom. as for the node data-range getting changed

Comment: where did you don't see the changes? in html tag or in js result?

Because there is a bug where the data attribute are not updated on the html

Comment: in console I am trying to print the result in console. after button click

Answer (score 1):

### Update

Actually to set the data attribute, don't you want to use `.data()`?

```
focus.data("range", x.domain());

function generateMenu() {

    return this.closest('svg').is(':focus').data('range');

}
```

End Update

---

Another update... .  Or if this works with your code, you could remove the generateMenu function.

```
function drawSvg(){
  ....// code to generate svg element with data provided
   var range = this.$element.selector,this.options.data.closest('svg').is(':focus').data('range');

     // do something with range

  .... // code to update the data when zoomed
  focus.data("range",x.domain()); //focus is object created in d3 of a node <g class="focus">
}
```

Comment: actually I am using d3 all the nodes are generated in d3. so I am adding the data attribute by svg function d3.attr("data-range",x.domain())

Comment: when you use dev tools to view the code, does the data attribute change on the html element ?   If you are retreiving the value through .data() you should be able to use it to set it as well.  Did you even bother to try my code?